# Load image/file stored in FTP server on WebView

Tags: ios, swift, webview, ftp

I'm trying to load an image stored in a FTP server on a webview. The problem is that using

```
let url = "ftp://example.com/images/image1.jpg"
let requestURL = NSURL(string:url)
let request = NSURLRequest(URL: requestURL!)
webView.loadRequest(request)
```

only shows a white screen because the FTP server asks for a username and password to grant access. So my question is: **how can I authenticate myself so the image from the ftp url loads in the webview?**

Answer (score 0):

You can build the URL using this [mask](https://www.cs.rutgers.edu/~watrous/user-pass-url.html).

```
ftp://username:password@hostname/
```

---

```
let login       = "LoginName"
let password    = "Password"
let ftpServer   = "ftp.server.com"
let fileName    = "example.txt"

let ftpUrl = NSURL(string: "ftp://\(login):\(password)@\(ftpServer):21/\(fileName)")
```

Comment: Try it like `ftp://user:pass@ftp.server.com/carpet/image1.jpg` and did not work.

Comment: Maybe you have to set NSAllowsArbitraryLoads  <key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict>
    <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
    <true/>
</dict>